# ssms tools pack unauthorized access exception

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

Just installed tools pack for ssms 2008

http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/Download

Keep seeing this on start up, most functions appear to work fine, just really annoying, cannot figure out what it's trying to do that is so bad, I'm running this as Administrator, still doesn't fix the error...

```
Exception Type:System.UnauthorizedAccessException
Error Messsage:
   Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.
Extra Data:
   - Method: SSMSToolsPackC10.dll.WindowColoring.InitialLoadServersToSettings
Error StackTrace:
   at System.Security.AccessControl.Win32.SetSecurityInfo(ResourceType type, String name, SafeHandle handle, SecurityInfos securityInformation, SecurityIdentifier owner, SecurityIdentifier group, GenericAcl sacl, GenericAcl dacl)
   at System.Security.AccessControl.NativeObjectSecurity.Persist(String name, SafeHandle handle, AccessControlSections includeSections, Object exceptionContext)
   at System.Security.AccessControl.NativeObjectSecurity.Persist(String name, AccessControlSections includeSections, Object exceptionContext)
   at System.Security.AccessControl.NativeObjectSecurity.Persist(String name, AccessControlSections includeSections)
   at System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemSecurity.Persist(String fullPath)
   at System.IO.File.SetAccessControl(String path, FileSecurity fileSecurity)
   at System.Configuration.Internal.WriteFileContext.DuplicateTemplateAttributes(String source, String destination)
   at System.Configuration.Internal.WriteFileContext.DuplicateFileAttributes(String source, String destination)
   at System.Configuration.Internal.WriteFileContext.Complete(String filename, Boolean success)
   at System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigHost.StaticWriteCompleted(String streamName, Boolean success, Object writeContext, Boolean assertPermissions)
   at System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigHost.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigHost.WriteCompleted(String streamName, Boolean success, Object writeContext, Boolean assertPermissions)
   at System.Configuration.Internal.DelegatingConfigHost.WriteCompleted(String streamName, Boolean success, Object writeContext, Boolean assertPermissions)
   at System.Configuration.ClientSettingsStore.ClientSettingsConfigurationHost.WriteCompleted(String streamName, Boolean success, Object writeContext)
   at System.Configuration.UpdateConfigHost.WriteCompleted(String streamName, Boolean success, Object writeContext)
   at System.Configuration.MgmtConfigurationRecord.SaveAs(String filename, ConfigurationSaveMode saveMode, Boolean forceUpdateAll)
   at System.Configuration.Configuration.SaveAsImpl(String filename, ConfigurationSaveMode saveMode, Boolean forceSaveAll)
   at System.Configuration.Configuration.Save()
   at System.Configuration.ClientSettingsStore.WriteSettings(String sectionName, Boolean isRoaming, IDictionary newSettings)
   at System.Configuration.LocalFileSettingsProvider.SetPropertyValues(SettingsContext context, SettingsPropertyValueCollection values)
   at System.Configuration.SettingsBase.SaveCore()
   at System.Configuration.SettingsBase.Save()
   at System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.Save()
   at p.e()

--------------- Filtered Assemblies ---------------
PostSharp
   Full Name: PostSharp, Version=3.1.49.9, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b13fd38b8f9c99d7
   File Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\SSMS Tools Pack\SSMS Tools Pack 2008\PostSharp.dll
   File Version: 3.1.49.0

SSMSToolsPack10
   Full Name: SSMSToolsPack10, Version=3.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a49c9b5533ef3445
   File Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\SSMS Tools Pack\SSMS Tools Pack 2008\SSMSToolsPack10.dll
   File Version: 3.2.2.0

SSMSToolsPackB10
   Full Name: SSMSToolsPackB10, Version=3.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a49c9b5533ef3445
   File Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\SSMS Tools Pack\SSMS Tools Pack 2008\SSMSToolsPackB10.dll
   File Version: 3.2.2.0

SSMSToolsPackC10
   Full Name: SSMSToolsPackC10, Version=3.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a49c9b5533ef3445
   File Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\SSMS Tools Pack\SSMS Tools Pack 2008\SSMSToolsPackC10.dll
   File Version: 3.2.2.0
```

Comment: Also cannot seem to be able to generate inserts based on filters, like in pic on features page, just dont see the option to do this anywhere

Comment: you should e-mail Mladen about this issue - he can likely provide direct support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error indicates you don't have write permissions on the folder:

> C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft_Corporation\DefaultDomain_Path_LongAlphaNumericSequenceHere\10.50.xxxx.x\

And it can't save the settings.

As for the other stuff, email me through the website and we can talk further.

Comment: I am in an "Enterprise" environment, my AppData folder is on a network drive, not sure why it's trying to write to C:\users, ill check registry... Unless that behavior is hardcoded?

Comment: Why do we need to "talk further" on ur site there's a pic, where it can generate inserts for a table based on where clause, however when i run the tool, i dont see this option available anywhere? Luckily the tables im working with now are small, so no biggy, but if i had a giant table, then it would be an issue, i can of course make a script or use excel todo this, was just looking for a way to mitigate my exposure to the mundane :)

Comment: there are 2 insert functionalities. the one you need is in the Object Explorer context menu when you right click on the table item under SSMS Tools menu item. The other one is scripting of result sets which is accessible on the result set grid context menu.